# Ruby determining whether a letter is uppercase or not

Tags: ruby

The question is very simple and probably have thousand of answers, but i am looking for some magical ruby function.

Problem:
`To determine whether a letter is upcase or not i.e belongs to A-Z.`

Possible Solution:

```
array = ["A","B", ....., "Z"]
letter = "A"
is_upcase = array.include? letter
```

Please note that "1" is not an uppercase letter.

Is there any magical ruby function which solve the problem with less code?

Comment: After reading some solutions and did some tests myself, I discovered that this is not a trivial problem. The solutions (I saw) do not consider characters like umlauts (`ä` => `Ä`), diacritic signs (`é` => `É`) or signs with more complex rules (`ß` => `SS`). Even Ruby's `#upcase` method does not handle such strings right. Therefore +1 for the question.

Comment: @spickermann Thanks. All the answers given are pretty awesome. What do you think is the best solution? I am confused within Cary Swoveland and Ray Toal solutions.

Comment: It appears `x == x.upcase` also works, as `x.upcase` is nil if `x` is not a letter.

Comment: @CarySwoveland nopes consider "1".upcase == "1" , will return true but is not an uppercase letter.

Comment: Sorry, Sahil, you are correct.  That should be `x == x.upcase!`.

Comment: @sahildhankhar: I think there is no solution in the moment, because characters that are pretty common in other languages (`Ä`, `È`) are not considered. If you do not care about non ASCII chars than I like @hirolau's solution or mine ;-).

Comment: @spickermann, I think your argument is for what the question should have been, not for what it is.

Comment: @CarySwoveland upcase! will not work either :)
 `"A".upcase! => nil`

Comment: @spickermann check out Stefan's answer. It handles non ascii cases also.

Comment: @sahildhankhar: Yes Stefan's answer does the job. Great!

Comment: That's what I get for not testing my code before posting it.  Shame on me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use POSIX [character classes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes):

- `/[[:lower:]]/` - Lowercase alphabetical character
- `/[[:upper:]]/` - Uppercase alphabetical

Example:

```
def which_case(letter)
  case letter
  when /[[:upper:]]/
    :uppercase
  when /[[:lower:]]/
    :lowercase
  else
    :other
  end
end

which_case('a') #=> :lowercase
which_case('ä') #=> :lowercase
which_case('A') #=> :uppercase
which_case('Ä') #=> :uppercase
which_case('1') #=> :other
```

Or with a simple `if` statement:

```
puts 'lowercase' if /[[:lower:]]/ =~ 'a'
#=> lowercase
```

Comment: most verbose solution.

Comment: @sahildhankhar just wrap the relevant part in a method, e.g. `String#lowercase?`

Comment: Great solution! Most (all?) other answers don't account for non ASCII letters

Answer (score 2):

Use `===`

```
?> ('A'..'Z') === 'C'
=> true
>> ('A'..'Z') === 'c'
=> false
>> ('A'..'Z') === '1'
=> false
>> ('A'..'Z') === '&'
=> false
>> ('A'..'Z') === 'Z'
=> true
```

Comment: wow!! where can i read more about === which explains this behavior?

Comment: found this one too at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Quite an under appreciated method in Ruby.  Good to see someone using it.

Comment: From the ruby style guide: Avoid explicit use of the case equality operator. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide `.cover?` and `.include?` do the exact same thing with less confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
'A' =~ /[A-Z]/ #=> 0 (boolean true)
'a' =~ /[A-Z]/ #=> nil (boolean false)
```

Comment: thanks . this works. but i am not willing to use a regex for this case in particular. But this works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Also lacks support for umlauts, diacritcs etc. und needs `ActiveSupport`, but I like the syntax:

```
'A'.in?('A'..'Z')  # => true
'a'.in?('A'..'Z')  # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_upcase? x 
  ('A'..'Z').cover? x
end
```

Edit: `.cover?` is a new function in 1.9 that checks if value is in range by only checking the endpoints. In that way the computer does not need to convert it into an array and store it in memory, making it faster.

It is basically another way of writing `x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z'`

Comment: found explaination at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F . Please include it as a part of the answer.

Comment: @sahildhankhar: `cover?` returns true if the argument is greater or equal that the start value and smaller or equal than the end value of the range. Unfortunately is also does not cover umlauts and diacritic signs.

Answer (score 1):

x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z'

Comment: this is by far the most simple and easy to understand solution.

Comment: @Arup, you should not be editing questions and answers unless you have a very good reason for doing so.  Adding a few spaces is not a good reason.  Personally, I would never edit someone else's answer for any reason, though I might leave a comment suggesting an edit.  That's because I view it as their intellectual property.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I rolled it back!! Sorry..:(

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to check if the character is uppercase

```rb
# false
c = 'c'
p c=~/[A-Z]/
p c==c.upcase
p /[A-Z]/===c
p (?A..?Z)===c
p ?A<=c&&c<=?Z
p (?A..?Z).cover?c
p c=~/[[:upper:]]/
p /[[:upper:]]/===c

# true
C = 'C'
p C=~/[A-Z]/
p C==C.upcase
p /[A-Z]/===C
p (?A..?Z)===C
p ?A<=C&&C<=?Z
p (?A..?Z).cover?C
p C=~/[[:upper:]]/
p /[[:upper:]]/===C
```

`=~` returns a `nil` or `0`.

`!!nil == false`; `!!0 == true`.

P.S. Not all of them works in the same way

- `'.' == '.'.upcase` => `true` but it's not a capital letter
- If you need to check letters with diphthongs use
  `/[[:upper:]]/==='Ñ'` => `true` as expected
- In this case you can to add interested letters manually:
  `/[A-ZÑ]/==='Ñ'` => `true`